# RxJava2 Iterate list and call single for every item

Tags: kotlin, rx-java2

I have a database table with friend connections:

The next example is just a `Imagined` example, so please not suggest me to implement this in another way.

FriendConnection:

- id
- humanId

I have a list with these id's.

```
val friendConnections = arrayListOf(
    FriendConnection(id=10, humanId=141),
    FriendConnection(id=13, humanId=142)
)
```

I want to make this result list with RxJava.

```
val friendList = arrayListOf(
    Friend(friendConnectionId = 10, humanId = 141, humanInstance = (...)),
    Friend(friendConnectionId = 13, humanId = 142, humanInstance = (...))
)
```

How I can get a human?

```
fun getHumanById(id: Long) : Single<Human>
```

So I need to iterate the `friendConnections` and make a Single call for every Human. Than I need to map the FriendConnection with the new Human instance to Friend instance.

I tried it but it's not work:

```
Observable.fromIterable(arrayListOf(
                FriendConnection(id=10, humanId=141),
                FriendConnection(id=13, humanId=142)
        ))
                .flatMapSingle { friendConnection ->
                    repository.getHumanById(friendConnection.humanId)
                            ?.map {human ->
                                Friend(friendConnection.id,friendConnection.humanId,human)
                            }
                }
                .toList()
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe({ it ->
                    Timber.i("friendList is here: $it")
                }, {
                    throw it 
                })
```

Someone have idea what's wrong? (I want to implement it with Rx, not with Room)

[image]

Comment: What result do you have? Why safe call is used in `repository.getHumanById(friendConnection.humanId)?.map` if you have `fun getHumanById(id: Long) : Single<Human>` signature?

Comment: Why you want to do this with Rx ? you can achieve this using kotlin operators itself.
is your `repository.getHumanById` making call to API ?

Comment: No, it's just a local database call.

Comment: Are you sure that `fun getHumanById(id: Long)` returns `Single<Human>` and not `Single<Human>?`(nullable type) ?

Comment: Because in the expression`repository.getHumanById(friendConnection.humanId)?.map {...}`  question mark denotes nullable type.

Comment: It's nullable now, but i tried with !!. It not works and here is no error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this solution suitable for you?

```
Observable.fromIterable(
        listOf(
            FriendConnection(1, 101),
            FriendConnection(2, 102)
        )
    )
        .flatMapSingle { connection ->
            getHumanById(connection.humanId)
                .map { human -> Friend(connection.id, connection.humanId, human) }
        }
        .toList()
        .subscribe { list -> println(list) } //method reference generates error due to methods ambiguity
```

Mock function for getting a human by id:

```
private fun getHumanById(id: Long): Single<Human> = Single.just(Human(id, id.toString()))
```

Comment: This does not work for me. I have 50 item in the friendConnection list, but only first 2 times called the flatMapSingle, why?

Comment: @vihkat, please, answer my comment under the question. Maybe the problem lies here.
Also, it would be cool if we could know why it does not work. Compile-time error, run-time error, unexpected result?

Comment: It works with your mock. But not work with my Single, but I'm sure it not returning null because I burned in a fix ID witch is work good

Comment: Are you completely sure that `getHumanById` returns exactly `Single<Human>` ? It is not either `Single<Human?>` or `Single<Human>?` or even `Single<Human?>?` ?

Comment: Yes. I'm sure about it

Comment: Then why `repository.getHumanById(friendConnection.humanId)?.map {... }` contains null assertion as a question mark?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this,

```
Observable.fromIterable(friendConnections)
        .flatMap { Observable.just(Friend(it.id, it.humanId, repository.getHumanById(it.humanId).blockingGet())) }
        .toList()
        .subscribe {it --> /*Your Operation*/
```

Comment: True. if `repository.getHumanById` makes API call then it should be `flatMap`. (Updated the answer based on assumption)

Comment: there is no assumption, it doesn't matter what the method is doing. It returns a Single, therefore you need flatMap